# Add dates everyday to a specific date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, t-sql

In SQL I want to take this startdate '2021-01-22'
and every day add data of a currentdate to that start date. So my datatable will always keep the start date, but every day add the newest date.

Tried something like this in my stored procedure;

```
DECLARE @DATESTART DATE;
DECLARE @DATEEND DATE;
SET @DATESTART =   '2021-01-22';
SET @DATEEND =  (SELECT DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 1, @DATESTART ), 1));
```

Comment: any reason not to use a TABLE with a CreateDate column and an ActualDate column, and have the latter increased/changed ?

Comment: What do you mean by "mSQL" ?? Should that be **MySQL**, or do you refer to **Microsoft SQL Server** ?? Please add the appropriate tag to your question to clarify!

Comment: it is microsoft sql server

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65841526/edit) and rephrase your question because it is not clear. The part "_and every day add data of a currentdate to that start date_" makes no sense to me. [1] You cannot add rows of data to a `date` type value? [2] Will you run your procedure infrequently or with a daily periodic schedule? [3] Would `2021-01-22` not be a bad example here? There are 0 days between that date and today. Your current `@DATEEND` equals tomorrow. [4] Do you need a list of dates for further calcuations or do want to insert new rows? Please add the expected output.

Comment: What table?  If a question references a table, I am expecting a table name, column names, and sample data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate dates since a certain date, you can use a recursive CTE:

```
with dates as (
      select convert(date, '2020-01-01') as dte
      union all
      select dateadd(day, 1, dte)
      from dates
      where dte < convert(date, getdate())
     )
select *
from dates
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

The results can be saved in a table.  Or the CTE can be incorporated into another query.